# How to Print a List of Files full name which is present in a shared drive (Location)

Tags: windows, excel, perl, shared-libraries

I have 5000 excel files in a shared location (drive) and my problem is in my local  machine I have a excel sheet which contains data of 500 excel files details only I just want to know different files name which is present in shared drive ,so Could you please explain how I got list of all excel files which is present in my shared drive How to Print a List of Files folders and there full name in a notepad or excel sheet.

Comment: Please share the code you have written.

Comment: Go to this link  
http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/print-list-of-files-in-directory/

Answer (score 0):

If running windows, you can run `dir /b *.xls > list_xls.txt`

To run it, open the command prompt, go to the network drive (using the cd command) and type the line above.

This will create a file containing the names of all the xls files.

Comment: When I am doing that I am getting this error

'\\em-web1-prod\UserFeedFiles\Extracts'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
'\\em-web1-prod\UserFeedFiles\Extracts\AgedMarginCalls'
CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.

Comment: My files are available in "' \\em-web1-prod\UserFeedFiles\Extracts '"" path

How to traverse through command prompt .

Comment: Do you have write access to this network drive?
If so, create a file named list_xls.bat and copy the previous line in it  (make sure it ends in .bat).
Then upload it to the network drive and run it by doubleclicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

use this command in your batch file

```
dir *.xls /b /s >>D:\test.xls
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".